# how to count last column in php

Tags: php

```
  6    abraham   26            2
  24   abraham   36            2
   2   albert    19            1
   4   babu      24            4
  15   babu      53            4
  99   babu      28            4
  76   babu      43            4
```

my question is.
how to echo last column values in this table

```
  6    abraham   26            **1**
  24   abraham   36            **2**
   2   albert    19            **1**
   4   babu      24            **1**
  15   babu      53            **2**
  99   babu      28            **3**
  76   babu      43            **4**
```

Comment: Can you paste some code snippet or mention what you have tried already?

Comment: In your SQL query use the order you want and `limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you have your example array in php, try using `array_column` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

In your example, if you wanted a new array with values of your last column, i.e. array(1,2,1,1,2,3,4), you could do:

```php
$fourth_column_array = array_column($full_array, 3);
```

Or if it's an associated array, it might look something like:

```php
$fourth_column_array = array_column($full_array, 'number_column');
```

Then to

> echo last column values in this table

You would do:

```php
foreach($fourth_column_array as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: can you paste some code

Comment: @RaheelAhmedSIddiqui can you paste some code

Comment: SELECT column_name
 COUNT(*) as 'Total_count' FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id GROUP BY column_name..          @JonathanClark

Comment: @RaheelAhmedSIddiqui Thanks, but that's SQL.  You say in your question "In PHP".  Can you improve your question?  Can you var_dump what you get back from SQL? can you try the code I've proposed?  Can you paste some PHP code?

Comment: how do this code in php ...... set @a=(select MAX(table_column)+1 as'max' from product where name  = 'raheel');   INSERT into table_name(id,Marks,name,count_column) values(null,100,'raheel',@a)

Comment: If you have the second block in your question outputting in mysql, then in php just run that same query, assign it to an array and then use the code from my answer.  You might want to make your question a lot clearer for me to be able to help more